# Not sure how to configure SPI bus on STM32L4xxxx

Tags: stm32, spi

I need to configure the SPI bus on a [STM32L452REY6TR](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/group3/fc/c2/8d/b7/99/d8/42/9e/DM00340549/files/DM00340549.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00340549.pdf) to work with an [ADS1282](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1282.pdf?ts=1667350564223) ADC. Page 25 of the the ADS1282 datasheet says:

*Data are shifted into DIN on the rising edge of SCLK and data are shifted out of DOUT on the falling edge of SCLK. If SCLK is held low for 64 DRDY cycles, data transfer or
commands in progress terminate and the SPI interface resets. The next SCLK pulse starts a new communication cycle. This timeout feature can be used to recover the interface when a transmission Figure 52. DVDD Power is interrupted or SCLK inadvertently glitches. SCLK should remain low when not active.*

The last sentence tells me that CPOL=0. Great. But how do I configure the CPHA? It seems like the STM32 SPI samples both MISO and MOSI at the same time, and you just pick if that is the rising edge or falling edge of the clock. The ADC, however, wants MISO and MOSI to be sampled on different edges.

What is the correct CPHA setting?

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with ADS1282, but looking at the timing diagram at page 5[image: timing diagram]

SPI seems to be half-duplex, thus you can use different CPHA for transmittion and reception.

But read your qoute from the datasheet more carefull:

*Data are shifted into DIN on the rising edge of SCLK* - i.e. DIN is sampled on the rising edge, thus CPOL=0, CPHA=0

*data are shifted out of DOUT on the falling edge of SCLK* - DOUT should be sampled rising edge too! Thus again CPOL=0, CHPA=0